# Notification of android foreground intent service not always removed

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-intentservice

In my app [uPod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.upod.app) I have several intent services performing one shot tasks like downloading episodes or synchronizing episode states. I run these tasks as foreground services with a notification shown in Android's status bar. From time to time, when the screen was off while the service was running, the notification isn't removed, though the service is finished (checked this in the task manager).

I'm not sure in these cases, whether the service finished gracefully or has been killed by Android due to lack of available resources (will add logging for this). Nevertheless according to my code I would expect the notification to be removed in ever possible case. But in these cases the only possibility to get rid of the notification is by bringing up the task manager and force kill the app.

Has anyone an idea, how to ensure, that the notification is removed in every possible scenario?

Here is my pseudo-code (original code is in Scala):

```
class SyncService extends IntentService("SyncService") ... {
  ...
  void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    final WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.acquire(AndroidPowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    wakeLock.acquire();
    try {
      startForeground(notificationId, notification);
      try {
        sync();
      } finally {
        stopForeground(true);
      }
    } finally {
      wakeLock.release()
    }
  }
  ...
}
```